# I can't configure Google Cloud Endpoints with Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to configure Google Cloud Endpoint for Google Cloud Run. 
I'm using the Google Cloud SDK version 250.0.0 (the latest available) and I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run. 
I was able to deploy an ESP, to Configure Endpoints and deploy the Endpoints configuration.
**I can't configure the ESP created** following the guide. If I run this command

```
gcloud beta run configurations update \
   --service CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME  \
   --set-env-vars ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME \
   --project ESP_PROJECT_ID
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.configurations) Invalid choice: 'update'.
Maybe you meant:
  gcloud components update
  gcloud firebase test android run
  gcloud firebase test ios run
  gcloud config configurations activate
  gcloud config configurations create
  gcloud config configurations delete
  gcloud config configurations describe
  gcloud config configurations list
  gcloud config set
  gcloud firebase test android locales describe
```

I've also searched the available commands for the `gcloud beta run configurations` here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/configurations/. The command `update` is not available, so maybe there's an error in the guide.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error in the docs, you should use the command:

```
gcloud beta run services update CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME --set-env-vars ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME --project ESP_PROJECT_ID
```

I've created a [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/135170358) to get this fixed. If you want to get updates on the progress you can star the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It fixed my problem but now I have another one. 
I finished to configure the Cloud Endpoints in front of Cloud Run using a custom domain but I can't see any logs, any incoming request in Cloud Endpoints. How is it possible?